# Using a Public Function across Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using a function that can separates out the numbers and letter within a cell. Code is below...

```
Public Function Strip(ByVal x As String, LeaveNums As Boolean) As Variant

    Dim y As String, z As String, n As Long
        For n = 1 To Len(x)
            y = Mid(x, n, 1)
            If LeaveNums = False Then
                If y Like "[A-Za-z ]" Then z = z & y 'False keeps Letters and spaces only
            Else
                If y Like "[0-9. ]" Then z = z & y   'True keeps Numbers and decimal points
            End If
        Next n
    Strip = Trim(z)
    End Function
```

Code works perfectly and isnt the issue, a college at work wants to be able to use the same function as its useful for a similar job she does. she is not very computer literate. How is she able to save the function on her own computer so that she is able to use the function for any task where it is required? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If she wants to use same function to any files to her computer then `add-in` would be best option. Here is a [article](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-add-in/).

Comment: Or save the function in the `personal.xlsb` of your computer and hers. See [Create and save all your macros in a single workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790)